# How to assign a sql query result to a variable in stored procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to assign a simple sql query result in stored procedure to a variable which I will use it later in another sql statement. If I execute below statement with out putting in procedure it works but not with stored procedure, I get an error while calling sp , Can someone please help me here ?

```
Procedure code:
$$
VAR NAME = 'ABC'
SET (COUNT_VALUE) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM COUNT_TABLE)

With out Procedure below code works
SET (COUNT_VALUE) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM COUNT_TABLE)
select $COUNT_VALUE
```

Thanks

Comment: What language are you using, JavaScript or SQL? If you want to store a result to a variable and use it later in the SP, right now you'll need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Here is some good discussion regarding your question, https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009QBItFSAX/store-a-query-result-in-a-variable-and-use-in-another-query-while-writing-procedure-in-snowflake

Comment: I am using JavaScript with SQL, still struggling any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that uses a simple helper function to return a result set from a query. You can read the Snowflake docs to see what the result set API has in it. The getResultSet function returns a variable that has the results of the query. Since the SQL is a count, you need to use rs.next() once to get to the first row and then read the value in the aliased count(*). You could also use rs.getColumnValue(1) to get a column by ordinal position, but I recommend using column names with SQL aliases is necessary.

```
create or replace procedure COUNT_EXAMPLE()
returns string
language javascript
as
$$

var rowCount = 0;
var sql = "select count(*) as ROW_COUNT from SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF10000.ORDERS;";

try {
    var rs = getResultSet(sql);
    if (rs.next()) {
        var rowCount = rs.getColumnValue("ROW_COUNT");
    } else {
        return "Error: Count query failed.";
    }
}
catch(err) {
    return "Error: " + err.message;
}

return "The table has " + rowCount + " rows.";

//--------------------------- End of main function ---------------------------

function getResultSet(sql){
    cmd1 = {sqlText: sql};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1);
    var rs;
    rs = stmt.execute();
    return rs;
}
$$;

call COUNT_EXAMPLE();
```

Comment: Thank you , I used next and getColumnValue to get the result ,